# Find the lowest value index in a numpy array per column plus value

Tags: python, numpy

This is quite easy:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2341)
data = (np.random.rand(3,4) * 100).astype(int)
```

so I have

```
[[35 20 47 39]
 [ 6 17 77 85]
 [ 8 25  2  3]]
```

Great, now lets get the indices of the smallest values per row:

```
kmin = np.argmin(data, axis=1)
```

this outputs

```
[1 0 2]
```

So in the first row, the second element is the smallest. In the second row the first and in the 3rd row it's the 3rd element. But how do I access those values and get them as one column?

I tried this syntax:

```
min_vals = data[:, kmin]
```

but the result is an 3x3 array. I need an output like this:

```
[[20]
 [ 6]
 [ 2]]
```

I know that I get the values on a different way too, but later on I have to implement Matlab code like this

```
data(1:n1,kmin,1);
```

where I need to select the lowest values again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.choose` function for it.

```
min_vals = np.choose(kmin, data.T)
```

I got this.

```
[20  6  2]
```

Comment: To meet the OP requirement the result can be changed to a column vector using `min_vals.reshape(-1, 1)`